# ClassNotFoundException during OSGI bundle startup

Tags: java, maven, osgi, blueprint, karaf

I have a problem which I just cannot seem to solve on my own. If have an OSGI Bundle which uses blueprint for instantiation of the Objects which should be deployed to Karaf 3.0.0.
The problem is, that ClassNotFoundExceptions keep bothering me, allthough the corresponding jars are located in the bundles jar. 
This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.kneipenapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>web-service</artifactId>
    <name>WebService</name>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Database connection -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-driver</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.29</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Camel -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-blueprint</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-sql</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Http Handler exposing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.grizzly</groupId>
            <artifactId>grizzly-http</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.11</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jersey -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Embed-Dependency>
                            *;scope=compile|runtime
                        </Embed-Dependency>
                        <Import-Package>
                            !*,
                            org.glassfish.grizzly.http,
                            org.apache.camel.component.sql,
                            org.osgi.framework
                        </Import-Package>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This is one of my blueprint xml files (this one is causing the ClassNotFoundException):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0">

    <!-- The camel context which will hold the routes -->
    <camelContext id="context" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
        <routeContextRef ref="newElementContext"/>
    </camelContext>

    <!-- The OSGI service beans which will be used to publish the service through the Grizzly Http Server -->

    <bean id="endpoint" class="org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl" factory-method="getInstance">
        <argument index="0" ref="endpointImplementation"/>
        <argument index="1" value="org.glassfish.grizzly.HttpHandler"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="endpointImplementation" class="com.kneipenapp.service.ServiceEndpoint">
        <argument index="0" ref="context"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- The pooled connection -->
    <bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DriverManagerConnectionFactory">
        <argument index="0" value="{{connection.url}}"/>
        <argument index="1" value="sqluser"/>
        <argument index="2" value="sqluserpw"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="pooledSQLConnectionFactory" class="PooledSqlConnectionFactory">
        <argument index="0" ref="connectionFactory"/>
        <argument index="1" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="poolConfig" class="org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPoolConfig">
        <property name="maxTotal" value="{{pool.maxConnections}}"/>
        <property name="maxIdle" value="{{pool.maxIdleConnections}}"/>
        <property name="minIdle" value="{{pool.minimumIdleConnections}}"/>
        <property name="maxWaitMillis" value="{{pool.waitInterval}}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="connectionPool" class="org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool">
        <argument index="0" ref="pooledSQLConnectionFactory"/>
        <argument index="1" ref="poolConfig"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource">
        <argument index="0" ref="connectionPool"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- The SQL endpoint used by the route -->
    <bean id="sql" class="org.apache.camel.component.sql.SqlComponent">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

</blueprint>
```

Finally this is the Exception and Stacktrace I recieve when I try to start the bundle:

```
org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: Unable to load class PooledSqlConnectionFactory from recipe BeanRecipe[name='pooledSQLConnectionFactory']
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.doLoadType(AbstractRecipe.java:195)[4:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.3.0]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.loadType(AbstractRecipe.java:161)[4:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.3.0]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.loadClass(BeanRecipe.java:249)[4:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.3.0]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.getType(BeanRecipe.java:895)[4:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.3.0]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.getInstance(BeanRecipe.java:323)[4:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.3.0]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate2(BeanRecipe.java:806)[4:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.3.0]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate(BeanRecipe.java:787)[4:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.3.0]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe$1.call(AbstractRecipe.java:79)[4:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.3.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)[:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)[:1.7.0_25]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:88)[4:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.3.0]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.RefRecipe.internalCreate(RefRecipe.java:62)[4:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.3.0]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:106)[4:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.3.0]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.getInstance(BeanRecipe.java:268)[4:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.3.0]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate2(BeanRecipe.java:806)[4:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.3.0]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate(BeanRecipe.java:787)[4:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.3.0]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe$1.call(AbstractRecipe.java:79)[4:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.3.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)[:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)[:1.7.0_25]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:88)[4:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.3.0]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.RefRecipe.internalCreate(RefRecipe.java:62)[4:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.3.0]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:106)[4:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.3.0]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.getInstance(BeanRecipe.java:268)[4:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.3.0]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate2(BeanRecipe.java:806)[4:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.3.0]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate(BeanRecipe.java:787)[4:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.3.0]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe$1.call(AbstractRecipe.java:79)[4:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.3.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)[:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)[:1.7.0_25]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:88)[4:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.3.0]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.RefRecipe.internalCreate(RefRecipe.java:62)[4:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.3.0]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:106)[4:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.3.0]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.setProperty(BeanRecipe.java:933)[4:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.3.0]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.setProperties(BeanRecipe.java:907)[4:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.3.0]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.setProperties(BeanRecipe.java:888)[4:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.3.0]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate2(BeanRecipe.java:820)[4:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.3.0]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate(BeanRecipe.java:787)[4:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.3.0]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe$1.call(AbstractRecipe.java:79)[4:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.3.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)[:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)[:1.7.0_25]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:88)[4:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.3.0]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createInstances(BlueprintRepository.java:245)[4:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.3.0]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createAll(BlueprintRepository.java:183)[4:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.3.0]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.instantiateEagerComponents(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:681)[4:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.3.0]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.doRun(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:378)[4:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.3.0]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.run(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:269)[4:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.3.0]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.createContainer(BlueprintExtender.java:276)[4:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.3.0]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.createContainer(BlueprintExtender.java:245)[4:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.3.0]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.modifiedBundle(BlueprintExtender.java:235)[4:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.3.0]
    at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:500)[2:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.0]
    at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:433)[2:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.0]
    at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$AbstractTracked.track(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:725)[2:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.0]
    at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:463)[2:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.0]
    at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$BundleEventHook.event(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:422)[2:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.0]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.invokeBundleEventHook(SecureAction.java:1103)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.createWhitelistFromHooks(EventDispatcher.java:695)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireBundleEvent(EventDispatcher.java:483)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireBundleEvent(Felix.java:4403)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2092)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:955)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundle(DirectoryWatcher.java:1247)[16:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.2.6]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1219)[16:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.2.6]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startAllBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1208)[16:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.2.6]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.process(DirectoryWatcher.java:503)[16:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.2.6]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:291)[16:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.2.6]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: PooledSqlConnectionFactory not found by com.kneipenapp.web-service [80]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1532)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:75)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1955)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)[:1.7.0_25]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.loadBundleClass(Felix.java:1844)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.loadClass(BundleImpl.java:937)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.loadClass(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:432)[4:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.3.0]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.loadClass(BlueprintRepository.java:410)[4:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.3.0]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.GenericType.parse(GenericType.java:113)[4:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.3.0]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.doLoadType(AbstractRecipe.java:168)[4:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.3.0]
    ... 63 more
```

If someone has a clue how this could be solved, I'd be more than happy to hear it

Greetings,
Pascal

Comment: Have you looked inside your built jar and confirmed that it physically contains the missing class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, you should use full qualified class name including the package name while specifying class parameter of the bean element. Like in the 'connectionFactory' bean above the 'pooledSQLConnectionFactory'.

Comment: Oh yes that was it :D I focused so much on the OSGI stuff assuming my blueprint definitions were correct. However, now I have a another problem which seems to be caused by the Aries Blueprint Implementation. I get the following exception when the "connectionPool" bean should be created: "Unable to find a matching constructor on class org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool for arguments [org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe$UnwrapperedBeanHolder@33c0ab2b, org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe$UnwrapperedBeanHolder@2e25ae98] when instanciating bean connectionPool"

Comment: This is strange because the types do match and as you can see - Aries does not seem to resolve the BeanRecipes correctly since he tries to find a Constructor with BeanRecipes (which will surely never be found)

Answer (score 0):

Your *connectionPool* is created by the constructor

`public   GenericObjectPool(PooledObjectFactory < T > factory,        GenericObjectPoolConfig config) {...}`

is your *class="PooledSqlConnectionFactory"* implementing  *PooledObjectFactory < T >* from [commons-pool2](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.commons/commons-pool2/2.0/org/apache/commons/pool2/PooledObjectFactory.java#PooledObjectFactory)
 or extending *BasePooledObjectFactory < T >*
with correct overrides, constructor etc?

You have to check if the arguments you give ( *pooledSQLConnectionFactory* and *poolConfig* ) are compliant with constuctor for *org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool*

Also, 
I don't know about Apache Aries, but maybe you also check how it works with Generics.

See
 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARIES-960
and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARIES-834

Comment: I got it to work finally. After solving the first Exception, there were a bunch of others which were related to missing transitive dependencies my module did not declare as imports in the manifest file.